# App Engine URL Fetch error: Malformed HTTP reply received from server

Tags: google-app-engine

We use url-fetch service in our Java (App Engine) backend and use it make an HTTP call to our other component that runs on container engine. For one specific request, we see that it quite consistent gives the following error :

```
java.io.IOException: Malformed HTTP reply received from server at URL: ...
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:159)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
```

I tried reproducing the same request that app-engine component makes using curl and couldn't reproduce the issue. The local app-engine server also works just fine against the very same container-engine-server.

It'a only happening when production app-engine makes a request to this container-engine-server.

I tried googling for "Malformed HTTP reply received from server" but hardly any results show up.

Any idea why this might be happening? The exception stacktrace mentions nothing more useful, just the URL being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check the length of your URL. As pointed out in the **[feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35892557)** the current maximum length is **2048 characters** for URL fetch. If this indeed is the cause of your problem, please add your voice to the feature request as well.

You should also read about the **[limits and quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/outbound-requests#quotas_and_limits_for_url_fetch)** for URL fetch.

One more thing to consider would be certificates for the URL that is being fetched. When App Engine is making an outbound HTTPS request (fetching URL) it checks for the certificate of the requested url. If for any reason the certificate is not valid, App Engine rejects the request. As per the documentation, to [disable host certificate validation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/issue-requests#disabling_host_certificate_validation) set the value of **`verify_peer`** to **`false`**.

Comment: 1. It's a POST HTTP Request. Length of the URL itself is quite small. Even the post body is quite small.  

2. I don't think it's due to limits / quotas. While this particular request is failing, other URL-fetch based requests are proceeding normally at the same time.  

3. The URL being fetched is http based. No https certificates involved here.

Comment: @Rohsan if this issue is still not resolved, can you share a sample code?